# Number theory proof help: If $p\in{Z}$ is prime, $w\in{Z[\sqrt{3}]}$, and $|N(w)| = p$, prove $w\sim\bar{w}$ if and only if $p =2$ or $2$.

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing, prime-numbers

Let $p$ be an ordinary prime with an extended integer $w = a+\sqrt{3}b$ such that $|N(w)| = p$. Prove that $w\sim\bar{w}$ if and only if $p = 2$ or $3$. 
($\textbf{Hint}$: If $w = a + b\sqrt{3}$ and $p\neq3$, first show that $p\nmid a$ and $p\nmid b$. Then use worksheet 18, problem 4. Problem 2 from worksheet 19 may also be helpful)

{$\textbf{Note}$: In wkst 18.4 we proved: For nonzero extended integers $w$ and $z$, prove that $w\sim z$ if and only if both $N(w) = N(z)$ and $\frac{w}{z}$ is an extended integer.}

{$\textbf{Note}$: In wkst 19.2 we proved: Let $p$ be an ordinary prime number, and suppose $w$ is an extended integer such that $|N(w)| = p$, then $p\nmid b$.}

{$\textbf{Note}$: I reference handout 7, which is just a list of extended integers and the norm associated with them.}

---

$\textbf{Proof}$:

$\Rightarrow$ We proceed with the contrapositive, that is if $p>3$, then $w\nsim\bar{w}$. Since $p>3$, $p\neq 3$ and, from worksheet 19 problem 2, we see that $p\nmid b$ and similarily that $p\nmid a$. We know that $N(w) = p = N(\bar{w})$. However, we have $\frac{w}{\bar{w}}$ and by multiplying by $\frac{w}{w}$ we are left with

$\frac{w}{\bar{w}}\cdot\frac{w}{w} = \frac{(a+\sqrt{3}b)^2}{\pm p} = \frac{a^2+2ab\sqrt{3}+3b^2}{\pm p}$.

We already know that $p\nmid a$ and, since $p$ is prime, $p\nmid a^2$. It follows that $p\nmid 3b^2$ and $p\nmid 2ab\sqrt{3}$. This implies that $\frac{w}{\bar{w}}$ is NOT an extended integer, hence $w\nsim\bar{w}$ and thus the forward portion of the proof is complete.

$\Leftarrow$ We say that if $p=2$ or $p=3$ then $w\sim\bar{w}$.

If $p=2$ we have $|N(w)| = 2$ which, from handout 7, we see that $N(w) = -2$. Then, from worksheet 19 problem 2, we see that $p\nmid b$ and $p\nmid a$. We see that $N(w) = -2 = N(\bar{w})$ and the fact that $N(w) = -2$ implies that $w = 1+\sqrt{3}$ and $\bar{w} = 1-\sqrt{3}$. Taking

$\frac{w}{\bar{w}} = \frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{1-\sqrt{3}} = -2-\sqrt{3}$,

which implies that $\frac{w}{\bar{w}}$ is an extended integer hence, by worksheet 18 problem 4, $w\sim\bar{w}$.

If $p = 3$, we have $|N(w)| = 3$ which implies that $|a^2-3b^2| = \pm3$. We know that $N(w) = N(\bar{w}) = \pm3$. Looking at $\frac{w}{\bar{w}}$ we see that by multiplying by $\frac{w}{w}$ we get

$\frac{w}{\bar{w}}\cdot\frac{w}{w} = \frac{w^2}{\pm 3}$.

We are now left with $\frac{w}{\bar{w}} = \frac{w^2}{\pm 3}$. Rearranging the equation, we are left with

$\pm 3 = w^2\cdot\frac{\bar{w}}{w}$.

Since $3$ is prime, we know that either $w^2$ or $\frac{\bar{w}}{w}$ is a unit. However, since $3$ is prime, $w$ is also prime which implies that $w^2$ is NOT a unit which means $\frac{\bar{w}}{w}$ MUST be a unit. We now have $\frac{\bar{w}}{w} = k$, where $k$ is unit and, by multiplying by $w$, we are left with $\bar{w} = w\cdot k$ which is the definition of associates and therefore $\bar{w}\sim w$ and consequently $w\sim\bar{w}$.

I'm curious if this proof works? Also, could I use the reasoning for the case of $p=3$ for the $p=2$ case as well?

Comment: How do you know for certain that $\frac{w}{\bar{w}}$ is not an extended integer? That feels like it's missing here.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I believe I have addressed this in the new edit.